# In flex, how to find the number of characters that can be fit for a text control of a given height?

Tags: apache-flex, text, character

In flex, I have mx:Text component. How can I find how many characters can fit into it without vertical scroll for a certain height & font etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the [TextLineMetrics](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html) class.

But, I imagine things might be a bit tricky if you're dealing with multiline text.